# Using serverless deployment, how do I restrict access to one AWS Lambda to a subset of IP addresses

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, serverless

I am deploying several AWS lambda functions that are accessed via AWS API Gateway. I want to restrict one of these functions so that it can't be accessed unless you are in a particular IP address range (our VPN), while allowing the rest of the functions to be open to anyone who calls them. Can I do this? If so how. I have seen several examples where restriction of access to a subset of ip's is done by configuration of the provider section of the serverless yaml. However that would affect all of my functions and I don't want to have any of my other functions affected.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IP based control to your API gateway can be done either by a WAF, or a custom Authoriser function, (might be called Lambda Authorizer now).  See [here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/using-enhanced-request-authorizers-in-amazon-api-gateway/) for an example. You can specify a Lambda function in your serverless yaml for this `authorizerFunc`. There is [support](https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/events/apigateway/) for this in serverless. For the endpoints you want protected from certain IPs put: `authorizer: authorizerFunc` in the `events` section, and leave the other endpoints which you want accessible to all alone.